# Android registration and login app error

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have made an app that's supposed to register new users in a DB(mySQL) with which the users can log into the app. The problem I have is that when I try to press the button for either login or register I get the error can't turn java string into JSONObject.

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    final TextView tvRegisterHere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

    tvRegisterHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
        }
    });

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if(success){
                            String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                            int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", name);
                            intent.putExtra("username", username);
                            intent.putExtra("age", age);

                            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                        } else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

LoginRequest.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by ---- on 2016-09-24.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "Webserver with my php file";
private Map<String, String> params;

public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}

RegisterActivity.java

package com.loginregister.loginregister;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);

        }
    });
}
}
```

RegisterRequest.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by ---- on 2016-09-24.
 */

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "Webserver with my php file";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("age", age + "");
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Login.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $username, $age, $password);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Register.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.loginregister.loginregister">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UserAreaActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>¨
```

The error log for LoginActivity

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.loginregister.loginregister.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:49)
W/System.err:     at com.loginregister.loginregister.LoginActivity$2$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:45)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The error log for RegisterActivity

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.loginregister.loginregister.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:44)
W/System.err:     at com.loginregister.loginregister.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:40)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 2):

You API is not giving proper JSON format. A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace)

See below code

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject("{your String}");
```

in your case response String is not correct

Comment: response string does not have proper json

Comment: But isn't it converted to a JSON string in the php files?
echo json_encode($response);

Comment: Check your API response via REST API client

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound stupid(I'm quite new to android development) but by the REST API do you mean the volley?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very unfamiliar with the usage of API tests, I did however follow this youtube guide. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Z4GVFaT4A&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka&index=4

Comment: It works fine when I download his code from GitHub but when I do the same I get this error.
GitHub: https://github.com/tonikami/NEWLoginRegister